# Proving the validity of an algorithm to solve $y' = f_1y+f_2$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, recursive-algorithms

Inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2475835/213607),
if we have the differential equation

$${y_1}'= f_{11}(x)y_{1}+f_{12}(x)$$

Under which conditions can we be sure that the iteration by factoring $f_{11}\cdot\left(y_1+ \frac{f_{12}}{f_{11}}\right)$ followed by substitution $y_2 = y_1+\frac{f_{12}}{f_{11}}$, rewriting a new differential equation in terms of $y_2$:
$${y_2}'= f_{21}(x)y_{2}+f_{22}(x)$$ and iterating will finish at some $n$ at a form:

$${y_n}' = f_{n1}(x)y_n $$
( Which can then be solved with the chain rule and we can backtrack a solution $n\to n-1 \to \dots\to 1$ )

Comment: Undoubtedly the faster way to solve such a problem is by variation of parameters.

Comment: @MichaelLee : Please link a reference if you have any. I have not heard about it before.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First_order_equation

Comment: Ah, okay yes then I have seen them, just did not know that name for them. Maybe this approach could lead further in some respect, even though you may not consider it simpler/faster?